# Why is there a horizontal acceleration if there is no horizontal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

Assume a non uniform sphere, on a smooth horizontal floor. Its center of mass isn't at its geometrical center, but on the line passing through geometrical center and parallel to horizontal floor.

My textbook claims that it will move with a horizontal acceleration and rotate with an angular acceleration. I have no doubt about the angular acceleration as there is a net torque in some direction.

But what about the horizontal acceleration? Both the gravitational and the normal force are opposite to each other in vertical direction. How will the horizontal acceleration produced?

Comment: Simper scenario, imagine a rigid stick at an angle with a mass on the end, what force comes to mind then, the word rigid being key

Comment: Since there would be no horizontal acceleration on a frictionless floor, as clearly explained by other answers, I'm wondering whether the problem implies that the floor is not frictionless, but just not bumpy so the sphere will roll nicely.

Comment: What textbook is this in?  Can you give a reference?

Comment: @pwf it is not a known one but my friend recommended. Name of the author is John Hooke.

Comment: What is the title, and what level student is it aimed at?  This is a nice junior-in-college-level dynamics problem, but very confusing for freshman or high school level.

Comment: @pwf this is aimed for 1st year college students. It contains only conceptual questions (no numericals). The title is Some ConceptDraw for physics

Comment: Even simpler example: when you try to walk, no one pushes you, it is you who pushes against the ground and due to friction(and reaction force), you move forward. The same logic extends here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the floor is smooth (i.e. absolutely no friction) and horizontal then there is no horizontal force acting on the sphere and hence no horizontal acceleration. If the sphere is initially stationary then it will just rotate back and forth, with its centre of mass moving up and down along a vertical line.

If there is friction between the sphere and the floor then this friction provides a horizontal force which accelerates the sphere horizontally.

Comment: This isn't quite right.  You are correct that there is no horizontal acceleration for the CM, and so the CM will only move up and down, but in order for the CM to maintain its horizontal position the ball will shift left and right.  The point of contact will not remain constant - if the CM starts to the right of the point of contact, later, when the CM is at its lowest point, the point of contact will be below it, and then as the CM rises the point of contact will be to the right of the CM.  If the CM is interior and not on the surface, the ball will both roll and slip back and forth.

Comment: @pwf Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: @pwf do you mean sphere will oscillate about initial position horizontally?

Comment: @Chesx Yes, the geometric center will.

Comment: @pwf So is there any criteria we can found horizontal acceleration (or velocity maybe). Just after releasing?

Comment: Yes, the problem can be solved using torques about the point of contact with the surface.  It turns out to be a lot like a physical pendulum, except that the moment of inertia is not constant but is changing with angle.  Sorry I don't have time to write up the details just now.  At the moment of release, the horizontal acceleration is $-rRmg/I$, where $r$ is the radius to the CM, $R$ is the radius of the ball, and $I$ is the (instantaneous) moment of inertia of the ball about the point of contact.

Comment: @pwf Horizontal acceleration of what? The centroid? As you have already pointed out, there is no horizontal acceleration of the COM.

Comment: @BobD Yes, horizontal acceleration of the geometric center (not the CM, since there is no net horizontal force).

Comment: @pwf I think this isn't quite right. The point of contact is moving. So shouldn't you add the pseudo for that to which we are calculating? i.e. about POC $I\alpha=mgr-maR$ where $\alpha$ is initial angular acceleration and $a$ is initial acceleration of POC and rest you know. And by this $a$ we can find acceleration of geometric center.

Answer (score 2):

The first observation is that the normal force does not have to have the same magnitude as the gravitational force.  They are not an action/reaction pair.  Normal force on the floor must be the same size as normal force on the sphere.  Gravitational force on the ball's center of mass must be the same size as the corresponding force on the Earth's center of mass.  Net external force equals mass times the acceleration of the object's center of mass.

If smooth means zero friction, then there is no external horizontal force, so the center of mass cannot accelerate horizontally.  As it begins at rest, it must move vertically.  The normal force, whatever it may be, provides angular acceleration around the center of mass.  The normal force will end up being whatever is necessary to coordinate the angular velocity around the C of M with the velocity of the C of M so as to keep that C of M acceleration vertical.  The normal force will change as needed.  The sphere must remain in contact with the floor to maintain the normal force.

Although the sphere does rotate and appear to move, it does not actually "roll".  The ball will slide along the floor as necessary to hold to Newton's 2nd Law for rigid extend objects:  net external force equals total mass times acceleration of the center of mass, net external torque around the center of mass equals rotational inertial around the cnter of mass times angular acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

> How will the horizontal acceleration produced?

It won't if the surface is completely frictionless and horizontal, because only friction can produce a horizontal force acting on the sphere in response to the applied torque. Without friction the sphere will essentially spin in place, i.e., spin with no horizontal motion relative to the floor.

I suggest the sphere will be behave as follows:

If the sphere is initially released from rest as shown in FIG 1 below with the center of mass (COM) located to the right of, and in line with, the geometric center, it will initially rotate clockwise, due to the clockwise torque about the geometric center created by gravity.

It will reach maximum angular velocity when the COM is directly above the frictionless surface as shown in FIG 2.  It will continue rotating until the COM again comes to rest at its original height as shown in FIG 3. The rotation will then reverse as shown in FIGs 4 and 5 and the whole process repeat itself.

In this manner I suggest the COM of the sphere will rotate from side to side in place, similar to the motion of the bob of a pendulum.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is almost right.  The ball will not rock around its geometric center, but about its CM.  In your diagram, the CM points should all align vertically.  Meanwhile, the CM will bob up and down as constrained by the shape of the ball and the floor, and the sphere will appear to rock from side to side as it bobs up and down.  (Yes, frictionless surfaces are weird!)

Comment: How about the initial acceleration (just after release). Will it still rotate at its own place?

Comment: @pwf what do you mean by rock side to side?

Comment: @Chesx what do you mean by “its own place”?

Comment: By "rock side to side," I mean that the geometric center will shift left and right.  The CM will not, but from the outside it will look like it is (since when we see a round balll we tend instinctively to assume its CM is at its geometric center).  Line your images up so the CM dots are all vertically aligned and I think you'll see what I mean.  Fig's 1 and 5 will be shifted to the left relative to 2 and 4, and Fig 3 will be shifted to the right.

Comment: @pwf how can the geometric center shift left and right if there is no horizontal force acting on the sphere?

Comment: The geometric center shifts BECAUSE there is no horizontal force.   The CM has to stay at a constant horizontal position. But because the CM is off-center, that means the outer surface of the ball (and the geometric center) will have to shift back and forth as the ball rotates.

Comment: But for the geometric center to move back and forth doesn't the sphere have to roll back and forth?

Comment: Actually, if the CM is interior and not on the surface, it slips more than it rolls (although it is simultaneously rotating about the CM, so it's kind of a rolling-with-slipping situation).

Comment: But as I understand it, rolling while slipping requires kinetic friction for the rolling part. Here we are assuming no friction exists.

Comment: @BobD I mean Center of mass will move in a vertical line. So doesn't that implies sphere will not remain at its original position in at which it was kept.

Comment: @Chesx But that would imply the initiation of rolling. The initiation of rolling requires friction. Here we are assuming no friction. That's what I'm wrestling with. I'm attempting to draw the situation where the COM moves vertically only.

Comment: @BobD but that would imply COM will have horizontal motion. But how without horizontal force?

Comment: @pwf For purpose of discussion I have temporarily added a diagram showing the motion of the sphere based on my understanding of your description of its behavior. In drawing the sequence I made the following two assumptions: (1) The distance between the centroid and the COM is fixed (the sphere being a rigid body) and (2) There is no horizontal motion of the COM (the net horizontal force on the sphere being zero), only vertical motion.

Comment: Following FIG 5 the rotation of the sphere reverses and the sphere returns (rolls? slides? combination of rolling and sliding?) to its original position of FIG 1. Is this what you had in mind? I’m starting to come to your way of thinking, but still have some doubts.

Comment: @Chesx See my comments above to pwf.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  It's a combination of rolling and sliding - there is rotation about an axis through the CM, but to do that and stay in contact with the table, there has to be slippage.  (Try it with a can lid - pinch it at an off-center point and rotate it around that point while keeping it on the table.  Only let the pinch point move up and down, not sideways.)